# Why does a photomultiplier tube (PMT) traditionally present better signal-to-noise ratio (SNR) than an avalanche photodiode (APD)?

Tags: visible-light, experimental-physics, measurements, error-analysis, signal-processing

Empirically, a photomultiplier tube (PMT) is said to present better signal-to-noise ratio (SNR) than an avalanche photodiode (APD). Some materials say that it is attributed to the higher gain and lower dark current of PMT.

The benefit of higher gain is confusing to me, since I suppose that noise (from incident photons and from the PMT detector) and signal are both amplified by gain. Why does higher gain result in better SNR?

Answer (score 2):

You have quoted that photomultiplier tubes have a *higher gain and lower dark current* than avalanche photodiodes and considered that noise and signal are both amplified by gain, 
but what is important is the ***lower dark current*** of photomultiplier tubes compared with avalanche photodiodes.

This means that there is less inherent noise associated with photomultiplier tubes, so for the same signal they will present a better signal-to-noise ratio than avalanche photodiodes.

Comment: Thank you, Mick. The lower dark current of PMT indeed matters.  Then does it mean that you don't  think that higher gain helps to better SNR? That is exactly what makes me confusive. I have read something like "higher gain of PMT gives more amplified signal, but does not increase noise". But I cannot understand, my thinking is just aforementioned "noise and signal are both amplified by gain".

Comment: Consider, if you have a particular SNR at the input then at the output of an _ideal_ amplifier (no internal noise) both the signal and the noise have been amplified, but the SNR is the same as at the input because both have been amplified by the same multiplication factor. But in a real amplifier there is some internal noise (interference, dark current, etc.) so at the output the signal has been amplified, but also the noise has been amplified _plus extra noise has been added within the amplifier itself_.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about the difference between PMT and APD, but if PMT has a higher gain than APD, than perhaps a larger portion of photons reaching the PMT can be detected than APD.

The number of photons hitting a detector in a particular time interval have a Poisson distribution with a parameter $\lambda$ in which $P(X=k)=\frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!}$. If the possibility of a photon being detected is $g$, then the distribution of the detected photon number is a Poisson distribution with a parameter $g\lambda$.

Since the expectation of a Poisson distribution variant is $\lambda$ and the standard deviation is $\sqrt{\lambda}$, the SNR is $\frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{\lambda}}=\sqrt{\lambda}$. This leads to the SNR of detected photons to be $\sqrt{g\lambda}$, which means a larger gain (a larger detection rate) leads to a larger SNR.